# XSD: How to define dependent attributes?

Tags: attributes, xsd

I need to define a schema where I have one attribute that must be defined when another optional attribute is existent.

Example:

```
<someNode defaultValue="Hello" /> <!-- valid -->
<someNode defaultValue="Hello" defaultValueTranslatable="true" /> <!-- valid -->
<someNode defaultValueTranslatable="true" /> <!-- NOT valid -->
```

How can I define this in my xsd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't I'm afraid. XSD supports optional attributes but does not support the conditional functionality you desire.

Comment: That's sad. I actually felt it intuitive that such a feature would exist.

Comment: You could consider writing xsd 2.0 ;)